# Spark Yarn Error during closing SparkContext

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, spark-ui

My Spark application works in a Yarn Hadoop cluster. After completing its tasks and attempting to close the `SparkContext`, my application encounters an error:

```
2023-06-05 12:30:43,361 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: SUCCEEDED, exitCode: 0
2023-06-05 12:30:43,370 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
2023-06-05 12:30:43,384 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@2c9541b7{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:0}
2023-06-05 12:30:43,390 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://.............:42705
2023-06-05 12:31:13,380 ERROR util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread shutdown-hook-0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1257)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.stop(AsyncEventQueue.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anonfun$stop$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anonfun$stop$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.stop(LiveListenerBus.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$6.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1922)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1361)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1921)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:573)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1992)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
2023-06-05 12:31:13,380 WARN util.ShutdownHookManager: ShutdownHook '$anon$2' timeout, java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.executeShutdown(ShutdownHookManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:95)
```

When I run the application with the deploy-mode set to "client," there is no error. However, when running it in cluster mode, the error occurs. Additionally, I have included a `sleep(300000)` function in the driver code, and in this case, there is no error either.

Comment: What spark version? Have you tried searching JIRA for related issues? Are you able to upgrade?